# bootstrap date picker position

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I am using following sample code for date picker

```
<html>
<head>
<!--  jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Isolated Version of Bootstrap, not needed if your site already uses Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />

<!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>


</head>
<body>
<div class="bootstrap-iso">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <!-- Form code begins -->
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input 1-->
            <label class="control-label" for="date">Start Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input 2-->
            <label class="control-label" for="date">End Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="date1" name="date1" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <!-- Submit button -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
 <!-- Form code ends --> 
    </div>
    </div>    
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
            var date_input1=$('input[name="date1"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
            var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
            var options={
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                container: container,
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
            };
            date_input.datepicker(options);
            date_input1.datepicker(options);
        })
    </script>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

The date picker for `Start Date` opens in correct position but for `End Date` the date picker open above the field. I want to open it below similar to first case. I guess the problem is with javascript and javascript is new new thing for me. How can I correct mistake?

Comment: add orientation: 'bottom' in your options variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using anything new in programming it's best to consult the documentation for the tool in question to discover what you can and can't do. In this case I did a google search for the bootstrap-datepicker and I found the docs here: [Options Doc](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#orientation)

after reading the docs you'll find there is a property called orientation you can set. Revising your options variable to the following should correct your issue:

```
var options={
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            orientation: 'bottom'
        };
```

Let me know how that goes!

Answer (score 3):

If you add orientation: 'top' to your options, it should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/L4t68rzx/1/

```
var options={
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: 'top' 
};
```